# Extract table from variable number of field column data in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data pasted into column A that I would like to convert into a table by extracting only some of the information to end up with a table.

In general, the question is also what is the best way to select desired data and organize this into a table when data exists in one single column that is semi-structured--it follows a general order for each unique set of data, but it includes variable number of fields for each unique set.

This is analoguos to, for example, if you had pasted JSON for a database information into a single column and each unique record might have a variable number of fields, what would be the best way to quickly assemble a table of the desired elements? Is it a query, matching, indexing or as I have provided in my attempt below.

In the example below, I am setting up a meeting for James Madison so I need to select only some of the information pasted into column A while ignoring other information to end up with something that looks like this:

| Name | Date | Phone | Time | Email |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James Smith | 08/19/1745 | 5555555555 | 9:00 AM | JamesSmith@people.org |  |  |

The data pasted into A2 is semi-structured--it follows a general order for each person, but it includes variable data, when it comes to information such as phone numbers. Some individuals have a work or home phone.

Note that some of the data repeats and could be used to split up the data (ie "PNPending arrival")

The semi-structured dataset:

| Pasted in A2 |
| --- |
| James Smith |
| 08/19/1745 |
| M. (555) 555-5555 |
| 9:00 AM |
| James Madison |
| JamesSmith@people.org |
| PNPending arrival |
| Rebeca Charlseton |
| 08/20/1745 |
| M. (222) 222-4444 |
| 9:30 AM |
| James Madison |
| RebecaCharlseton@people.org |
| PNPending arrival |
| Samantha Homers |
| 08/21/1745 |
| M. (312) 999-7777 |
| 11:00 AM |
| James Madison |
| SamanthaHomers@people.org |
| PNPending arrival |
| Marco Polo |
| 08/22/1745 |
| M. (443) 444-4442 |
| W. (443) 444-4442 |
| H. (443) 444-4442 |
| 11:30 AM |
| James Madison |
| MarcoPolo@people.org |
| PNPending arrival |

My formula and output:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("",PasteApppointment!A2:A31),"James Madison",""),"H..\(\d+\).\d+.\d{4}|W..\(\d+\).\d+.\d{4}",""),"M..\((\d+)\).(\d+).(\d{4})","$1$2$3"),"PNPending arrival",FALSE,FALSE)), "",FALSE,FALSE))
```

My formula does a few things, such as reformatting the mobile phone number that is kept so that it only has numbers, but basically it works by removing values that are not desired in this case "James Madison" and any phone number that starts with W or H, then splitting the remaining data with the work PNPending arrival.

Output form my formula:

| Name | Date | Phone | Time | Email |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James Smith | 08/19/1745 | 5555555555 | 9:00 AM | JamesSmith@people.org |  |  |
| Rebeca Charlseton | 08/20/1745 | 2222224444 | 9:30 AM | RebecaCharlseton@people.org |  |  |
| Samantha Homers | 08/21/1745 | 3129997777 | 11:00 AM | SamanthaHomers@people.org |  |  |
| Marco Polo | 08/22/1745 | 4434444442 | 11:30 AM | MarcoPolo@people.org | PNPending arrival |  |

Comment: You mentioned pasting this data in from somewhere—is there any way for you to change how it be original source data is structured? If it’s coming from a table on a website you might be able to leverage `=IMPORTHTML()`

Comment: ^^ Definitely the first thing you should consider.  Structuring the data this way will do nothing but cause you trouble.  If you can change it, do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
=index(let(Σ,to_text(A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>"")))),
       Δ,if(regexmatch(Σ,"James Madison|PNPending arrival|^W\.|^H\.|^$"),,if(regexmatch(Σ,"^M\."),regexreplace(Σ,"[^\d]",),Σ)),
       wraprows(tocol(Δ,1),5)))
```

- Incase there's any ***other variables*** that you encounter later & need to be excluded (so that solution doesn't go haywire), you could add them to the existing list in this part of the formula here

---

```
regexmatch(Σ,"James Madison|PNPending arrival|^W\.|^H\.|^$")
```

---

[image]